# Mac won't stay connected to the domain

Tags: active-directory, mac, mac-osx

I have a few Macs that I want to join up to a Windows domain, when I join the test machine to the domain it works fine but when I reboot the computer it looses it's connection and I have to delete it and re-create it.

My Mac is called "macbook1" the domain is "lancaster.local" the Mac is running Mac OS X 10.6.1

I have performed the process described in http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3789?viewlocale=en_US and the problem still persists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you disabled Bonjour on the Mac? Bonjour/Zeroconf uses the *.local domain which causes issues with domains that actually use .local.

The program that is in charge of Bonjour, `mDNSResponder` now also handles DNS for your Mac as well so disabling it like you could in 10.4 or 10.5 will result in issues with anything related to DNS for any GUI applications. Apple has posted a kbase article (http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3789?viewlocale=en_US) in order to do this. I'm not in an AD environment so I don't have any first hand experience with AD and Snow Leopard.

Comment: No, how do i do that?

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears to have been that the mac couldnt resolve dc.domain.tld properly. I added the line:

```
IP dc.domain.tld dc
```

to */etc/hosts* and it works fine now.